# Strange Unclearable Cache Issue with Gmail and Google Apps

Tags: firefox, gmail, debug, browser-cache

I am having a strange issue with Gmail and Google Apps... have a look at this screenshot: http://cld.ly/f51ume

notice the missing images for the rounded corners?  Well this is not such a problem but something similar to a cache issue is causing this as well as no background image, but MOST IMPORTANTLY chat and other "clickable" features aren't working.  I've already cleared my cache multiple times and quit and re-started Firefox with no change.  Everything is OK in other browsers.

Any other debug suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you are not on the page whenever you clear your cache and you check all the boxes including Site Preferences and choose Everything from the time range box.  Other than that no idea, good luck.

Comment: good suggestions, I did everything you mentioned before posting the question... still no luck :(  Tried it again now for good measure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I had somehow accidentally created a rule in Firefox preferences that was disallowing images from being downloaded from the Gmail server.  Once I deleted the exception, the images appeared normally again.